# Creating and populating a table in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to T-SQL and trying to learn how to create a script in T-SQL to create and populate a table(StaffData).The StaffData is defined as below:

---

```
staffid – integer primary key, identity starting at 1, increments by 1
managerid – int, allows nulls, pointer to another record in managertable
name – string of 50 characters
salary – money
```

---

What can I do to generate table and fill it with set of data..?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the correct SQL. I've tested it (just spotted that you want managerId nullable - I've added this):

- it uses better conventions for your table and column names (you shouldn't be using 'data' in table names - we know it contains data)
- it names your primary key constraints, which is better practice - you can do something similar for the FK constraint if you want, I've just done it inline
- it uses 'USE' and 'GO' statements to ensure you're creating things on the right database (critical when you're working on big production systems).
- it uses nvarchar columns - you need these to reliably store data from international character sets (e.g the manager has a Russian name)
- I'm using nvarchar(max) as you can't be sure that a name will only be 50 characters. Use nvarchar(50) if you must, but database space isn't usually a big deal.

You need to create the Manager table first, as your Staff table depends on it:

```
USE [yourDatabaseName] -- you don't need the square brackets, but they don't hurt

-- Create ManagerTable
CREATE TABLE Manager
    (
       id int IDENTITY(1,1),
       name nvarchar(max),
       CONSTRAINT pk_manager PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )

CREATE TABLE Staff
    (
       id int IDENTITY(1,1),
       name nvarchar(max),
       salary money,
       managerId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Manager(id) NULL,
       CONSTRAINT pk_staff PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )


--To populate Manager table:

INSERT INTO [Manager]
    (
        -- id column value is auto-generated
        name
    )
    VALUES
    (
       'John Doe'        
    )    

--To populate Staff table:

INSERT INTO [Staff]
    (
        -- id column value is auto-generated
        name, salary, managerId
    )
    VALUES
    (
       'Jane Doe', 60000, 1       
    )

GO
```

Answer (score -1):

**To create the two database tables:**

```
-- Create StaffData
CREATE TABLE StaffData
    (
       staffid int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
       managerid int
    )

-- Create ManagerTable
CREATE TABLE ManagerTable
    (
       managerid int,
       name varchar(50),
       salary money
    )
```

**To populate StaffData table:**

```
INSERT INTO [StaffData]
    (
        --staffid - this column value is auto-generated
        [managerid]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        -- staffid - int
        12345 -- managerid - int
    )
```

**To populate ManagerTable table:**

```
INSERT INTO [ManagerTable]
    (
        [managerid],
        [name],
        [salary]
    )
    VALUES
    (
        12345, -- managerid - int
        'Juan Dela Cruz', -- name - varchar
         15000 -- salary - money
    )
```

**To select the data if i understand you in your word `Pointer` here is the query using `INNER JOIN` joining the two tables using their `managerid`**

```
SELECT *
FROM [StaffData]
     INNER JOIN [ManagerTable] 
     ON [StaffData].managerid = [ManagerTable].managerid
```

Comment: Hi Japz. This has a number of issues. See my answer - hope you find it useful ;)

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow , yup :) i intentionally not doing the perfect code for the person who ask, such as creating foreign keys etc., what i gave is the basics because i wanted the person who post the question to do some research.. don't want to feed all but to give a little knowledge on how to `create` , `insert` and `select`. hehe.. anyways thanks :)

Comment: The `joining` part is a bonus for him :)